# CouchDB: save multiple attachments at once using python-couchdb API?

Tags: python, couchdb

I want to save multiple attachments in one pass into the couchDB, I know how we can save a single attachment like this (using python-couchdb):

```
db.put_attachment(doc, content, attachment_name, content_type)
```

but I couldn't find anythingg on web on how to store multiple attachment in one request trough the API?
Know that We can an do it trough PUT request as mentioned [here](https://wiki.apache.org/couchdb/HTTP_Document_API#Multiple_Attachments), but Iwant to do it using client API.

Comment: Why did I get a down vote, can any one tell me if  my question is wrong? Some clarification can help me to see if I'm going to a wrong way or not. I'm new to noSQL and CouchDB and I not completely familiar with its concept. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I assume you're using [python-couchdb](http://pythonhosted.org/CouchDB/client.html).

It maps directly to the HTTP API. Presumably `db.save` is the one you want.

If it's not supported, you can of course just use the HTTP API directly, e.g. via [requests](http://docs.python-requests.org).

Comment: Then there's no way to do it. Go raise a bug/feature request here: https://github.com/djc/couchdb-python/issues

Comment: Are there any other python client API that support it or not? If  python-couchdb is a one-to-one map of  couchDB API, it should have a method like put_multiple_attachment besides put_attachment, but there is no such thing.

Comment: No, there's no "put multiple attachment" in the HTTP API. There is "put/post document" and attachments can be provided in-line or via multipart/related.